# Family tourist visa for the UK

Tags: uk, standard-visitor-visas

I am applying for a UK tourist visa for a trip with wife and childern. I believe that each memeber should have their own application on gov.uk. I will be the one providing the finanical evidence. Wife is employed but income is low. How can I connect my finanical evidence to her application ?